# Objective C GET method working over WI-FI but not over cellular network

Tags: objective-c, get, twitter, httprequest

I have the following code to obtain the twitter Id and name from the Twitter API:

```
{

        NSString *StringUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=%@",account.username];

        @try {

                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
                [request setTimeoutInterval: 15];
                [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:StringUrl]];

                NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
                NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;

                NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];

                if([responseCode statusCode] != 200){
                    NSLog(@"Error getting %@, HTTP status code %i", StringUrl, [responseCode statusCode]);
                }else{
                    NSLog(@"Good");
                    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
                    NSString *twitterId = [json objectForKey:@"id_str"];
                    NSString *twitterName = [json objectForKey:@"name"];
                }

        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"No conection: %@",exception.name);
        }
}
```

It works fine when testing over wifi network; however over cellular network it responds with:

```
Error getting https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=enf_4eva, HTTP status code 400
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this was not the best way to do this kind of requests because the request must be authenticated over 3G. With the new SLRequest I could set the account that is doing the request so it works beautifully.